# Can't update to 3.1.x

Tags: updates

I'm in a multi config env, local, staging & production. I sync my databases down to local then usually update locally, then push to staging and check again before going live.

The recent 3.1 updates aren't working for me.
Usually, I go thru the control panel and all is fine.

Now I get the below. Minor issues for plugins I can usually sort out but how do I solve this one?

```
Composer output: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- craftcms/vue-asset 1.0.2 requires craftcms/cms ~3.0.0-beta.1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.37, 3.0.36, 3.0.35, 3.0.34, 3.0.33, 3.0.32, 3.0.31, 3.0.30.2, 3.0.30.1, 3.0.30, 3.0.29, 3.0.28, 3.0.27.1, 3.0.27, 3.0.26, 3.0.26.1, 3.0.25, 3.0.24, 3.0.19, 3.0.23.1, 3.0.23, 3.0.0-beta.1, 3.0.0-beta.2, 3.0.0-beta.3, 3.0.0-beta.4, 3.0.0-beta.5, 3.0.0-beta.6, 3.0.0-beta.7, 3.0.0-beta.8, 3.0.0-beta.9, 3.0.0-beta.10, 3.0.0-beta.11, 3.0.0-beta.12, 3.0.0-beta.13, 3.0.0-beta.14, 3.0.0-beta.15, 3.0.0-beta.16, 3.0.0-beta.17, 3.0.0-beta.18, 3.0.0-beta.19, 3.0.0-beta.20, 3.0.0-beta.21, 3.0.0-beta.22, 3.0.0-beta.23, 3.0.0-beta.24, 3.0.0-beta.25, 3.0.0-beta.26, 3.0.0-beta.27, 3.0.0-beta.28, 3.0.0-beta.29, 3.0.0-beta.30, 3.0.0-beta.31, 3.0.0-beta.32, 3.0.0-beta.33, 3.0.0-beta.34, 3.0.0-beta.35, 3.0.0-beta.36, 3.0.0-RC1, 3.0.0-RC2, 3.0.0-RC3, 3.0.0-RC4, 3.0.0-RC5, 3.0.0-RC6, 3.0.0-RC7, 3.0.0-RC7.1, 3.0.0-RC8, 3.0.0-RC9, 3.0.0-RC10, 3.0.0-RC10.1, 3.0.0-RC11, 3.0.0-RC12, 3.0.0-RC13, 3.0.0-RC14, 3.0.0-RC15, 3.0.0-RC16, 3.0.0-RC16.1, 3.0.0-RC17, 3.0.0-RC17.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.1, 3.0.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.3.1, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.0.10, 3.0.10.1, 3.0.10.2, 3.0.10.3, 3.0.11, 3.0.12, 3.0.13, 3.0.13.1, 3.0.13.2, 3.0.14, 3.0.15, 3.0.16, 3.0.16.1, 3.0.17, 3.0.17.1, 3.0.18, 3.0.20, 3.0.21, 3.0.22] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- craftcms/vue-asset 1.0.2 requires craftcms/cms ~3.0.0-beta.1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.37, 3.0.36, 3.0.35, 3.0.34, 3.0.33, 3.0.32, 3.0.31, 3.0.30.2, 3.0.30.1, 3.0.30, 3.0.29, 3.0.28, 3.0.27.1, 3.0.27, 3.0.26, 3.0.26.1, 3.0.25, 3.0.24, 3.0.19, 3.0.23.1, 3.0.23, 3.0.0-beta.1, 3.0.0-beta.2, 3.0.0-beta.3, 3.0.0-beta.4, 3.0.0-beta.5, 3.0.0-beta.6, 3.0.0-beta.7, 3.0.0-beta.8, 3.0.0-beta.9, 3.0.0-beta.10, 3.0.0-beta.11, 3.0.0-beta.12, 3.0.0-beta.13, 3.0.0-beta.14, 3.0.0-beta.15, 3.0.0-beta.16, 3.0.0-beta.17, 3.0.0-beta.18, 3.0.0-beta.19, 3.0.0-beta.20, 3.0.0-beta.21, 3.0.0-beta.22, 3.0.0-beta.23, 3.0.0-beta.24, 3.0.0-beta.25, 3.0.0-beta.26, 3.0.0-beta.27, 3.0.0-beta.28, 3.0.0-beta.29, 3.0.0-beta.30, 3.0.0-beta.31, 3.0.0-beta.32, 3.0.0-beta.33, 3.0.0-beta.34, 3.0.0-beta.35, 3.0.0-beta.36, 3.0.0-RC1, 3.0.0-RC2, 3.0.0-RC3, 3.0.0-RC4, 3.0.0-RC5, 3.0.0-RC6, 3.0.0-RC7, 3.0.0-RC7.1, 3.0.0-RC8, 3.0.0-RC9, 3.0.0-RC10, 3.0.0-RC10.1, 3.0.0-RC11, 3.0.0-RC12, 3.0.0-RC13, 3.0.0-RC14, 3.0.0-RC15, 3.0.0-RC16, 3.0.0-RC16.1, 3.0.0-RC17, 3.0.0-RC17.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.1, 3.0.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.3.1, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.0.10, 3.0.10.1, 3.0.10.2, 3.0.10.3, 3.0.11, 3.0.12, 3.0.13, 3.0.13.1, 3.0.13.2, 3.0.14, 3.0.15, 3.0.16, 3.0.16.1, 3.0.17, 3.0.17.1, 3.0.18, 3.0.20, 3.0.21, 3.0.22] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- craftcms/vue-asset 1.0.2 requires craftcms/cms ~3.0.0-beta.1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.37, 3.0.36, 3.0.35, 3.0.34, 3.0.33, 3.0.32, 3.0.31, 3.0.30.2, 3.0.30.1, 3.0.30, 3.0.29, 3.0.28, 3.0.27.1, 3.0.27, 3.0.26, 3.0.26.1, 3.0.25, 3.0.24, 3.0.19, 3.0.23.1, 3.0.23, 3.0.0-beta.1, 3.0.0-beta.2, 3.0.0-beta.3, 3.0.0-beta.4, 3.0.0-beta.5, 3.0.0-beta.6, 3.0.0-beta.7, 3.0.0-beta.8, 3.0.0-beta.9, 3.0.0-beta.10, 3.0.0-beta.11, 3.0.0-beta.12, 3.0.0-beta.13, 3.0.0-beta.14, 3.0.0-beta.15, 3.0.0-beta.16, 3.0.0-beta.17, 3.0.0-beta.18, 3.0.0-beta.19, 3.0.0-beta.20, 3.0.0-beta.21, 3.0.0-beta.22, 3.0.0-beta.23, 3.0.0-beta.24, 3.0.0-beta.25, 3.0.0-beta.26, 3.0.0-beta.27, 3.0.0-beta.28, 3.0.0-beta.29, 3.0.0-beta.30, 3.0.0-beta.31, 3.0.0-beta.32, 3.0.0-beta.33, 3.0.0-beta.34, 3.0.0-beta.35, 3.0.0-beta.36, 3.0.0-RC1, 3.0.0-RC2, 3.0.0-RC3, 3.0.0-RC4, 3.0.0-RC5, 3.0.0-RC6, 3.0.0-RC7, 3.0.0-RC7.1, 3.0.0-RC8, 3.0.0-RC9, 3.0.0-RC10, 3.0.0-RC10.1, 3.0.0-RC11, 3.0.0-RC12, 3.0.0-RC13, 3.0.0-RC14, 3.0.0-RC15, 3.0.0-RC16, 3.0.0-RC16.1, 3.0.0-RC17, 3.0.0-RC17.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.1, 3.0.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.3.1, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.0.10, 3.0.10.1, 3.0.10.2, 3.0.10.3, 3.0.11, 3.0.12, 3.0.13, 3.0.13.1, 3.0.13.2, 3.0.14, 3.0.15, 3.0.16, 3.0.16.1, 3.0.17, 3.0.17.1, 3.0.18, 3.0.20, 3.0.21, 3.0.22] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for craftcms/vue-asset 1.0.2 -> satisfiable by craftcms/vue-asset[1.0.2].

Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.
```

Composer file:

```
{
  "name": "craftcms/craft",
  "description": "Craft CMS",
  "keywords": [
    "craft",
    "cms",
    "craftcms",
    "project"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://craftcms.com/",
  "type": "project",
  "support": {
    "email": "support@craftcms.com",
    "issues": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues",
    "forum": "https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/",
    "source": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms",
    "docs": "https://craftcms.com/docs",
    "rss": "https://craftcms.com/changelog.rss"
  },
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "3.0.33",
    "superbig/craft3-mobiledetect": "1.0.1",
    "pennebaker/craft-architect": "2.2.11",
    "mikestecker/craft-readability": "1.0.4",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.1.6",
    "verbb/feed-me": "3.0.0",
    "verbb/redactor-tweaks": "2.0.1",
    "solspace/craft3-freeform-pro": "2.5.3",
    "nystudio107/craft-typogrify": "1.1.16",
    "rias/craft-position-fieldtype": "1.0.14",
    "svenjungnickel/redactor-font-awesome": "2.0.4",
    "dolphiq/iconpicker": "1.0.5",
    "verbb/super-table": "2.0.14",
    "superbig/craft3-templateselect": "2.0.0",
    "charliedev/section-field": "1.1.0",
    "dukt/facebook": "2.0.1",
    "joomkit/pdfthumbnailer": "1.0",
    "craftcms/guest-entries": "2.1.3",
    "nystudio107/craft-fastcgicachebust": "1.0.8",
    "studioespresso/craft-splashingimages": "1.1.0",
    "solspace/craft3-freeform": "2.5.3",
    "balazscsaba2006/cookiebot": "1.0.6",
    "nystudio107/craft-seomatic": "3.1.38",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.63.1",
    "bower-asset/bootstrap": "v3.3.7",
    "bower-asset/inputmask": "3.3.11",
    "bower-asset/jquery": "3.2.1",
    "bower-asset/punycode": "v1.3.2",
    "bower-asset/yii2-pjax": "2.0.7.1",
    "cakephp/core": "3.6.7",
    "cakephp/utility": "3.6.7",
    "craftcms/vue-asset": "1.0.2",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "v5.0.0",
    "google/auth": "v1.3.0",
    "google/cloud": "v0.71.0",
    "google/gax": "0.34.0",
    "google/protobuf": "v3.6.0.1",
    "grpc/grpc": "1.13.0",
    "hashids/hashids": "2.0.4",
    "hughbertd/oauth2-unsplash": "1.0.3",
    "imageoptim/imageoptim": "^1.3",
    "jakeasmith/http_build_url": "1.0.1",
    "kraken-io/kraken-php": "1.6",
    "ksubileau/color-thief-php": "v1.3.1",
    "league/csv": "8.2.3",
    "league/oauth2-facebook": "2.0.1",
    "masterminds/html5": "2.3.0",
    "michelf/php-smartypants": "1.8.1",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.8.32",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.23.0",
    "mtdowling/jmespath.php": "2.4.0",
    "mundschenk-at/php-typography": "v6.1.5",
    "nesbot/carbon": "1.32.0",
    "phenx/php-font-lib": "0.5.1",
    "php-science/textrank": "1.0.4",
    "pixel418/markdownify": "v2.1.11",
    "psr/cache": "1.0.1",
    "ralouphie/mimey": "1.0.8",
    "ramsey/uuid": "3.7.3",
    "rize/uri-template": "0.3.2",
    "sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser": "v1.5.2",
    "symfony/inflector": "v3.3.6",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "v1.8.0",
    "symfony/property-access": "v3.3.6",
    "symfony/translation": "v3.3.6",
    "tinify/tinify": "1.5.2",
    "unsplash/unsplash": "2.4.3",
    "aelvan/imager": "v2.1.2",
    "craftcms/element-api": "^2.5",
    "nerds-and-company/schematic": "4.1.0"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "plugins/joomkit/pdfthumbnailer/"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@composer dump-autoload -o",
      "@php craft setup/welcome"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This likely an issue in your composer.json file. Can you edit the original question to share it?

Answer (score 2):

Have the same issue with upgrading. In my case, the package itself doesn't appear in my `composer.json`. It does appear in my `composer.lock` file thought.

**Edit:** Removing the `composer.lock` and doing a fresh install fixed this issue for me. The package was a dependency for SEOmatic, but removing SEOmatic didn't remove it from my lock file.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
removed   "craftcms/vue-asset": "1.0.2"
and changed craftcms version number.
I also had to manually change a few required items as phpstorm seemed to be reverting their versions creating more problems

Comment: Yes i had a few quirks with SEOmatic as i accidentally upgraded production db then synced it to local and ran into troubles. Probably the worst experience after a few years using craft so once a blue moon is not all bad. I think the blitz vendor folder is a good way to go in future.